# Should I upgrade to Windows 10 from a non-bootable USB key?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I’ve recently upgraded six computers from Windows 7 to Windows 10, using a bootable USB memory key configured by going to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/. The first three were version 1903, but I reloaded the key with 1909 for the last three when that became available, hoping that would make the installation somewhat faster. In all cases, I retained the existing applications, accounts, and data files.

For the first upgrade, I initially booted from the memory key, but during the process I was instructed to start over, boot Windows 7 normally, and then execute setup.exe on the memory key. For all of the other upgrades, I did not even try booting from the key. In some of those cases, I had neglected to reset the BIOS to prevent booting from a USB device, and a subsequent reboot from it temporarily caused problems which I solved by removing the key.

It seems to me that, for the upgrade path I’m using, there is no advantage and there is some disadvantage to having the memory key be bootable. For future upgrades, I’m thinking of copying all of the visible installation files to a non-bootable key and using that instead. Does anyone have any experience working this way? Alternatively, has anyone found but not personally tried advice about this approach?

Comment: Chances are, your “non-bootable” flash drive will be bootable anyway. But I guess this question is mostly about whether or not the extra effort is worth it.

Comment: Windows 7 machines are getting old now, so you should upgrade BIOS, Chipset, Video, Network and all other drivers first. Then upgrade to Windows 10. It will not make a big difference whether the USB key is bootable or not. The system is not running Windows 10 so the upgrade has to start with the Windows 7 base and then authorize Windows 10

Comment: @John: Windows 7 drivers may not be too useful in Windows 10.

Comment: That may possibly be true, but it is good to start there so Windows 10 can do further driver updates

Comment: It has never been possible to upgrade and/or perform an in-place repair from the WinPE.  You have always had to boot to Windows to perform either of those functions.  If you are running a previous version of Windows you should use the Media Creation Tool and start the installation from within Windows itself.  If you are using Windows 10 then you should upgrade to the next version of Windows 10 through Windows Update.

Comment: Since @Ramhound's response was in the form of a comment, I can't accept it as the most useful answer, but I find it convincing. That makes me more comfortable about working from non-bootable Windows 10 installation media and avoiding the problem of accidentally trying to boot from it. I'll also have bootable rescue media, produced by my disk imaging software, available on a separate memory key, which is consistent with what harrymc suggests.

Comment: @Frogrammer-Analyst - My commentary was just that, commentary on how WinPE has worked, since the beginning of time.  I certainly didn’t answer any of your questions

Answer (score 1):

A bootable key will be useful if things go wrong and you find yourself with
a non-booting hard disk. This is recommended.

In order to be able to restore your disk if the worst happens, I suggest
taking a disk image backup and create another bootable CD/USB that can
restore the disk, in case.

A good backup/restore product is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/),
which also can create a boot CD/USB.